# Creating L-structures on domains

Tags: combinatorics, logic

I'm given the language $L=(R,g)$ and in this, $R$ is a relation of arity 3and $g$ is a function of arity 2.

If I have the domain {1, 2, 3, 4}, how many different L-structures can I make with this domain?

I have a side question: If the function is binary, does it send two inputs to one outputs or can it send it to two outputs?

and for $g$, is $g(1,2)$ the same as $g(2,1)$?

Thanks for your help

Comment: All functions, including binary functions only return one output (in logic).

No, g(1, 2) is not necessarily the same as g(2, 1).  The function g can only return numbers in {1, 2, 3, 4}, correct?  Does the relation R return truth values in {T, F}?

Comment: Oh okay thank you. I am not sure about the specific details of the question, it's all I have been given. I was thinking that I could have $4P4$ permutations of the relation symbol, i.e. R(1,2,3) or R(1,2,4) or R(2,3,4), etc.. but then each of these is either T or F and then I have the function say $g(1,2)$ going to 1,2,3 or 4. and then $g(2,1)$ to 1,2,3 or 4 and so on. Is this the right method?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood In the context of an $L$-structure $A$ with domain $D$, an $n$-ary function symbol $f$ is always interpreted as a function $f^A\colon D^n\to D$, and an $n$-ary relation symbol is always interpreted as a subset $R^A$ of $D^n$. Alternatively, it's possible to think about the interpretation of a relation symbol as a function $D^n\to \{T,F\}$ (the characteristic function of the subset: $R^A(a_1,\dots,a_n) = T \iff (a_1,\dots,a_n)\in R^A$), but the subset interpretation is much more common, probably because interpreting *relation* symbols as certain kinds of *functions* is confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D = \{1,2,3,4\}$ be your domain.

A relation symbol of arity $3$ is interpreted as a subset of $D^3$. What is the size of $D^3$? How many subsets does a set of size $k$ have?

A function symbol of arity $2$ is interpreted as a function $D^2 \to D$. What is the size of $D^2$? What is the size of $D$? How many functions are there from a set of size $m$ to a set of size $n$?

Answering the questions above should tell you how many choices you have for interpreting $R$ and interpreting $g$ on the domain $D$. Now an $L$-structure with domain $D$ consists of an interpretation of $R$ and an interpretation of $g$. How many choices do you have total?

Comment: ah yes, this is the exact method I was using as stated above in the comments. I understood the concept I just needed some clarifcation of, for example, $g(1,2) \ne g(2,1)$. For the function symbol, can I have $g(1,1)$? and I assume you cannot have $R(1,1,1)$ right?

Comment: A $3$-ary relation is interpreted as *any* subset of $D^3$. Of course you can have $R(1,1,1)$. And $(1,1)$ is an element of $D^2$, so it is one of the inputs to $g$. @juper

Comment: so I can also have $R(1,1,2)$ and what specifically is $D^3$?

Comment: $D^3$ is the Cartesian product $D\times D\times D$.